# Python last match

Tags: python, regex

How do I grab the "california" part in the following string?

```
http://states.com/_states/united_states/50/california
```

I'm trying the following but don't' know how to match the last /.

```
match = re.search(r'\/(.*)$', state_url)
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: I'm sure he has. It does not work.

Comment: You seem to be parsing URIs, so why not using the path part of this URI and grab the last component of the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
r'[^/]*$'
```

which matches any number of characters except `'/'` before the end of input
or ideally, for a URL,

```
r'[^/#?]*(?:$|[#?])'
```

which matches any number of characters that are non-special in a URL path part up to the end of input (`$`) or the end of the path part `[#?]`.  The `(?:...)` is just a parenthetical group that does not capture the contents.

---

Btw, appendix B of [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) is a great reference for parsing URIs with regular expressions.

> ## Appendix B.  Parsing a URI Reference with a Regular Expression
>
> As the "first-match-wins" algorithm is identical to the "greedy"
>     disambiguation method used by POSIX regular expressions, it is
>     natural and commonplace to use a regular expression for parsing the
>     potential five components of a URI reference.
>
> The following line is the regular expression for breaking-down a
>     well-formed URI reference into its components.
>
> ```
>  ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
>   12            3  4          5       6  7        8 9
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: `r'\/(.*?)$'` will not work for quite obvious reasons. The lazy quantifier and general `.` has no place here. Your first regex is what works: http://regex101.com/r/cJ9fQ3 (I would use a `+` instead of `*` though)

Comment: @Lindrian, Yeah.  I never remember which regex engines do PEG-style backtracking and which do Prolog-style backtracking with lazy operators.  Safer just to not rely on the difference between lazy and eager and make adjacent regex operators unambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you need regular expressions for this? What about the following?

```
In [66]: url = 'http://states.com/_states/united_states/50/california'

In [67]: url.split('/')[-1]
Out[67]: 'california'
```

But this depends on whether you always want to extract the last word in a URL, of course. I just wanted to mention it.